# Uninitialized Local Variable 'Quick' Used

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

I'm making this function which counts the total amount of swaps and comparisons a quick sort function would do in total. When I run it, however, I get this error:

> error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'quick' used

This happens in the 'if' statement for the base case listed in the function code below. SwapandComp is the name of the struct I am using to keep track of both the swaps and comparisons for the sorting, and partition is the function where we find where to separate the original array, and it is also where we count the swaps and comparisons.

```
int partition(int numbers[], int i, int k) {
int l = 0;
int h = 0;
int midpoint = 0;
int pivot = 0;
int temp = 0;
bool done = false;

// Pick middle element as pivot
midpoint = i + (k - i) / 2;
pivot = numbers[midpoint];

l = i;
h = k;

while (!done) {

    // Increment l while numbers[l] < pivot
    while (numbers[l] < pivot) {
        ++l;
        totalComps++;
    }

    // Decrement h while pivot < numbers[h]
    while (pivot < numbers[h]) {
        --h;
        totalComps++;
    }

    // If there are zero or one elements remaining,
    // all numbers are partitioned. Return h
    if (l >= h) {
        totalComps++;
        done = true;
    }
    else {
        // Swap numbers[l] and numbers[h],
        // update l and h
        temp = numbers[l];
        numbers[l] = numbers[h];
        numbers[h] = temp;
        totalSwaps++;

        ++l;
        --h;
    }
  }
  return h;
}
```

And now here is the quick sort function. As mentioned before, SwapandComp is the struct I used to keep track of both swaps and comparisons.

```
SwapandComp quicksort(int numbers[], int i, int k) {
SwapandComp quick;
int j = 0;
int z = 0;


// Base case: If there are 1 or zero elements to sort,
// partition is already sorted
if (i >= k) {
    return quick;
}

    // Partition the data within the array. Value j returned
    // from partitioning is location of last element in low partition.
    j = partition(numbers, i, k);

    // Recursively sort low partition (i to j) and
    // high partition (j + 1 to k)
    quickSort(numbers, i, j);
    quicksort(numbers, j + 1, k);

    quick.swaps = totalSwaps;
    quick.comps = totalComps;

    return quick;
}
```

On the second line down, I write

```
SwapandComp quick;
```

to use for the quick sort struct. The error doesn't really make sense to me because I did declare 'quick' as a new struct to have the function return. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The error says `uninitialized`. Where are you initializing it?

Comment: @Mat isn't is where I put `SwapandComp quick`? Or is that just declaring it and not initializing it?

Comment: @user10361655 With that you \*define\* quick. But its members are *default-initialized*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `struct` as bellow :

```
SwapandComp quick = { 0 };
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to look at this :). I did try doing as you said, but after putting that in, I get this error: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct SwapandComp __cdecl quickSort(int * const,int,int)" (?quickSort@@YA?AUSwapandComp@@QAHHH@Z) referenced in function "struct SwapandComp __cdecl quicksort(int * const,int,int)" (?quicksort@@YA?AUSwapandComp@@QAHHH@Z)` It's kind of hard for me to understand. I am still fairly new to C++

Comment: you have the function `quicksort()` but you call it as `quickSort()`, these are different names

Comment: pay attention the `error : `  `unresolved external symbol "struct SwapandComp __cdecl quickSort(int * const,int,int)` in `function "struct SwapandComp __cdecl quicksort(int * const,int,int)"`

Comment: Wow, I knew it was something that simple. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it does work now. Thanks! I have a bit of trouble finding the tiny mistakes. I really need to work on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SwapandComp quick;
```

Unless that type has a constructor, declaring a variable with it inside a function will leave it in an indeterminate state. Then returning it (without first initialising it, as per your base case) will cause exactly the issue you're seeing, a "using an uninitialised variable" warning.

You *could* just initialise the members when declaring it, such as with:

```
SwapandComp quick; quick.swaps = quick.comps = 0;
```

But a *better* way to do it is with a real initialisers, something like:

```
struct SwapAndComp {
    unsigned swaps;
    unsigned comps;
    SwapAndComp(): swaps(0U) , comps(0U) {};
};
```

This method (initialisation as part of the class itself) allows you to properly create the structure *without* any users of it needing to worry about doing it correctly. And, if you want flexibility, you can simply provide a constructor that allows it while still defaulting to the "set to zero" case:

```
SwapAndComp(unsigned initSwaps = 0U, unsigned initComps = 0U)
    : swaps(initSwaps) , comps(initComps) {};
```